# Get AWS sub account alias from main account

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

```
data "aws_iam_account_alias" "sub" {}

output "sub_account_alias" {
  value = upper(data.aws_iam_account_alias.sub.account_alias)
}

data "aws_organizations_organization" "test" {}

output "test_account_ids" {
  value = data.aws_organizations_organization.test.non_master_accounts[*].name
}
```

I'm trying to get any sub-account alias from a pipeline on the main account( in the case I provide a sub-account id)

Currently, `data.aws_iam_account_alias.sub.account_alias` will show the main account alias and `data.aws_organizations_organization.test.non_master_accounts[*].name` will show a list of accounts alias.

I read the docs about [iam_account_alias](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/iam_account_alias) & [organizations_organization](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/organizations_organization) but no place to put account id. Is it possible in Terraform or I have to use some tricks with shell, jq... to get a sub-account alias?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the account alias? Normally this only gets used for a human readable name for logging into the account via the console sign in portal. But it would be unusual to have multiple accounts in an Organization need this and instead you'd normally have a single account with IAM users in and then role assumption into other accounts or use AWS SSO instead.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I need to use it to create a monitoring dashboard, this dashboard was created from another 3rd tool but still use Terraform.

Comment: Any reason you wouldn't use the account name as returned by Organizations instead if you need a human friendly name for something here?

Comment: What do you mean the account name returned by Organizations?

Comment: The `aws_organizations_organization` data source returns the account names not the IAM account aliases. These are different things and used differently. If you could share how you are trying to use these it would probably be more useful to understand exactly what problem you're having.

Comment: I just want to get the sub-account name using sub-account id. I can easily add a new variable for sub-account name and everything will be simple.